# In Python multiple mysql db communication using ORM

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, peewee

Good day to All,

I need to communicate to DBs like here is the sample[image] using python & peewee.

First i need to put an entry in the types table of the MainDb. only the Name & type am having & the ID will get auto increment after the entryin the table, then using the auto incremented id(MainID), i need to put a data entry in respective type table of the respective type db.
 then i need to do some operation using the select queries with MainID in the python code and finally i need to delete the entries of the MainID in the MainDb as well as in the respective type db, if the operations in the python code gets executed successfully or not (throws any error or exception).

Currently i am using the simple db (MySQLdb) connection & close with cursor to execute the queries & to get the last auto incremented id am using lastrowid of the cursor(cursor.lastrowid).

And also i referred the [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448198/accessing-remote-mysql-database-with-peewee) as per my understanding its ok if i have an single db (like main db alone) but what am i need to do for my situation.

**OS**: Windows7 64bit,

**Db**: MySQL Db v5.7,

**Python** : v2.7,

**peewee** : v2.10

Thanks in advance